# Tool to report what codecs were used for audio and video encoding for all files in a folder

Tags: windows, mp3, encoding, avi

Looking for a tool to report what codecs were used for audio and video encoding for all files in a folder. I use GSpot but it does it on a file per file basis. I want a tool to do it for all files in a folder. For windows.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [MediaInfo](http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/en). It has a command line version and can output any detail(s) about media files.

For example, this command will print the encoding library used to create the audio stream:

```
MediaInfo --Inform=Audio;%Encoded_Library% "MyFile.mp3"
```

Or to get an overview of all the available properties:

```
MediaInfo MyFile.avi
```

For additional details see:

```
MediaInfo --help-inform
MediaInfo --info-parametes
```